# Why does INSERT INTO cause an overwrite in Hive?

Tags: hive, insert, overwrite

I am trying to insert rows into a table while keeping the existing data, but Hive overwrites whatever is already there. After executing the following, I expect 2 rows:

```
1 2
3 4
```

but only see 1 row (`3 4`) in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE `my_db.test_table`
(
    `x1` STRING
    ,`x2` STRING
)
LOCATION '/.../test_table'
;

INSERT INTO TABLE `my_db.test_table`
SELECT '1', '2'
;

INSERT INTO TABLE `my_db.test_table`
SELECT '3', '4'
;
```

According to [the Hive Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries), an overwrite should only happen with `INSERT OVERWRITE`, not with `INSERT INTO`.
What could cause this overwrite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the culprit: it's the backtick / backquote (`). The issue is noted [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-16907).

This will perform an overwrite:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE `my_db.test_table`
SELECT '3', '4'
```

while this will append:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE my_db.test_table
SELECT '3', '4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I tried the same at my end and was able to get the data appended one after another..

And as you stated only when we specify `OVERWRITE` hive will delete the data that was previously available.
[image]
Also you can see that the directory would now have two files, and for each consecutive `INSERT INTO` statement a new file will be created under the directory.

[image: Files under the Directory]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test_Table (X1 STRING, X2 STRING) LOCATION '/hive1';
```

Could you please try doing the same again and let us know if you still are facing the issue ?

Comment: Thanks! It looks like it's actually a bug in Hive. Check out the link in my answer.